# How do I use biomaRT to get the corresponding gene iDs

Tags: r, bioconductor, biomart

I have a txt file and it looks like this. I need to use biomaRT in R to get the corresponding gene IDs of a whole list of different Refseq and peptides. Along with that, I need to keep the peptide sequence with the final outcome How would I do that? Please help

```
myData = read.delim("phosphopeptides.txt", header = FALSE)
```

Comment: anyone having this issue? > library(biomaRt)
> ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = "genes", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
Ensembl site unresponsive, trying uswest mirror

Answer (score 1):

Using *refseq_peptide* to match our IDs:

```
library(biomaRt)

ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = "genes", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")

refseq_peptide = unique(myData$RefSeq)

res <- getBM(attributes = c("refseq_peptide", "hgnc_symbol"), 
             filters = "refseq_peptide",
             values = refseq_peptide, 
             mart = ensembl)
res
#   refseq_peptide hgnc_symbol
# 1      NP_000007       ACADM
# 2      NP_000009      ACADVL
# 3      NP_000012       PSEN1

#merge
merge(myData, res, by.x = "RefSeq", by.y = "refseq_peptide")
#      RefSeq                            Peptide hgnc_symbol
# 1 NP_000007                    R.SDPDPKAPANK.A       ACADM
# 2 NP_000009                    K.SDSHPSDALTR.K      ACADVL
# 3 NP_000012 K.YNAESTERESQDTVAENDDGGFSEEWEAQR.D       PSEN1
# 4 NP_000012            R.AAVQELSSSILAGEDPEER.G       PSEN1
# 5 NP_000012            R.AAVQELSSSILAGEDPEER.G       PSEN1
# 6 NP_000012                  R.S*LGHPEPLSNGR.P       PSEN1
```

---

**Note**: Useful function to find the attributes - *searchAttributes*, when we do not know the correct attribute name:

```
searchAttributes(mart = ensembl, pattern = "refseq")
#                        name                 description         page
# 86              refseq_mrna              RefSeq mRNA ID feature_page
# 87    refseq_mrna_predicted    RefSeq mRNA predicted ID feature_page
# 88             refseq_ncrna             RefSeq ncRNA ID feature_page
# 89   refseq_ncrna_predicted   RefSeq ncRNA predicted ID feature_page
# 90           refseq_peptide           RefSeq peptide ID feature_page
# 91 refseq_peptide_predicted RefSeq peptide predicted ID feature_page

searchAttributes(mart = ensembl, pattern = "hgnc")
#               name        description         page
# 64         hgnc_id            HGNC ID feature_page
# 65     hgnc_symbol        HGNC symbol feature_page
# 95 hgnc_trans_name Transcript name ID feature_page
```

Comment: Depending on where you are accessing it from (your IP address) the mirror you are accessing may be temporarily down, so you might have to wait. Could check website for status updates

Comment: Just `merge()` the two tables on the ID.

Comment: @KellyWong added "merge" step.

Comment: It will work on everything in `MyData`. So whatever is in that `.txt` for you're loading in.

Comment: You should ask that as a new question. It's out of scope for these comments